# User ranking with Java and SQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to determine the ranking of a user by their score from an external database using Java and SQL. Here's what I have so far:

```
    public int findRanking(User user){
         int count =0;
         if (c == null) {
         c = getConnection();
     }
     try{
        Statement s =c.createStatement();            
        String query="SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY SCORE DESC";
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            ..

        }

     }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception: " + e);  

     }
```

I'm not sure how to operate the while loop to return the ranking. If anybody has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SET @ranking := 0;
SELECT @ranking := @ranking+1 as ranking, * FROM (SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY SCORE DESC)
```

With this you will not need a while loop to determine ranking.

recommendation: instead of *, list the fields you are expecting -- query is faster then.

for a single user:

```
 SET @ranking := 0;
 SELECT * from (SELECT @ranking := @ranking+1 as ranking, * FROM (SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY SCORE DESC) U) W where userId='89'
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the method you provided has a syntax error, you close the function body after c=getConnection();
You should read the javadocs for resultset [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).
You can read your score by doing:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    score = rs.getInt("SCORE");
}
```

no need for a while loop, since you only want the score of one user :)
Also, this method does not return the score of a given user, it returns the highest score of all users. You should modify your query to do something along the lines of:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID = " + user.getId() + "ORDER BY SCORE DESC";
```

Do you see why?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I managed to do it by passing the username. This method is part of a class where I have a user login as well. So, by logging in I should grab the username and determine the ranking by the score position. Here's my final code:

Answer (score 0):

Final code. Thanks a lot guys for your help:

```
    public int findRanking(String username){
     int rank =1;
     if (c == null) {
        c = getConnection();}

     try{
        Statement s =c.createStatement();
        String query="SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY SCORE DESC";
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){ 
            String current=rs.getString("USERNAME");
            if(username.equals(current)){
                return rank;
            }
            else{
                rank++;
            }


        }


     }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception: " + e);  

     }
     return rank;

 }
```